# How to change a CSS rule annotation value: @import, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the URL only using JavaScript; The snippet is like:

```
 <style scoped>
   @import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
 </style>
```

The purpose is to change the URL by a variable, on some events in the HTML document, I want to inject a value string to the url rule.

Comment: Just remove the `style` tag and add a new one. Much easier than trying to mess with the CSSOM (in my opinion).

Comment: Mind describing exactly the result you wish to accomplish? Is this supposed to be dynamic at run time?

Comment: @HereticMonkey no option, it needs to be a scoped style.

Comment: ...`scoped` was removed from HTML a while ago (https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/137), so I doubt there's much support for it.

Comment: it is nice to know, thank you fo pointing out